# .htaccess fake folder domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns

i have a problem, i need to change

http://website.com/new/index.php

to

http://website.com/index.php

without changing wordpress settings at all,i know i can migrate wordpress to that domain, but i dont want to mess the things up.

I was trying to do it with .htaccess but i din not managed to do such thing, any help will be appreciated

I need just to imitate the url in address bar.

Comment: which directory contain source code?

Comment: the wordpress site is in /new/ but i need all content with links and all to display in website.com/ directory

Comment: By trying to "not mess things up" you are creating a nightmare for yourself. Change the settings; it's the only clean way of changing the url(-prefix) of your wordpress.

Comment: if i understand right, anchors generated by wordpress are http://website.com/smthg while really are located at ttp://website.com/new/smthg? I.e., you need to add /new to url? In the case write in .htaccess RewriteRule ^.*$ new/$1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 RewriteRule ^new/index\.php$ /index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: the wordpress site is in /new/ but i need all content with links and all to display in website.com/ directory

i mean all links neet to be from website.com/new/test.html to website.com/test.html etc..

Comment: RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]